# Is it a joke or an overstatement about 素书?

Tags: culture, books

I saw the title of this book素书 yesterday and it was said to be the most wonderful book in the world(天下第一奇书) according to the author writing the introductory article. But when I inquired about this book from a dozen of teachers and friends of China who are all graduates of higher education, nobody recalled that they had ever read it or even heard of it.

So, to be honest, without checking it online or doing research, do you know about this book, dear friends of this forum? Is 天下第一奇书 a joke or an overstatement?

Comment: IF YOU GOOGLE OR 百度 "天下第一奇书", YOU WILL GET A LOT OF RESULTS. 素书 IS ONE OF THEM IF YOU ARE LUCKY ENOUGH.

Comment: if you have this quote in your book, google would pick it up

Answer (score 0):

[image]

It isn't well known but:

**素书相传为秦末黄石公作，民间视为奇书、天书。**[《素书》](https://www.8bei8.com/book/sushu.html)以道家思想为宗旨，集儒、法、兵的中国传统哲学思想发挥道的作用及功能，同时以道、德、仁、义、礼为立身治国的根本、揆度宇宙万物自然运化的理数，以此认识事物，对应事物、处理事物的智能之作。传说黄石公三试张良，而后把此书授予张良。张良凭借此书，助刘邦定江山。

Answer (score 0):

天下第一奇书 (the most amazing book in the world) is purely a personal opinion. The guy who wrote it either believed so, or he over-praised it for the publisher's benefit. Not even the Bible can make this claim without many people objecting to it, at least most non-Christians would

It is more likely an overstatement than a joke

> without checking it online or doing research, do you know about this book?

I have never heard of this book

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly, I have never heard of it without looking.

That said, I would not take any such statement seriously, regardless of how good or bad the thing really is.  Look at any ad, tv commercial or book or movie, they will all tell you how wonderful it is.  No one will ever approve an advertisement saying "our book is mediocre, but buy us anyway okay?" That is what the outer cover is, an advertisement, trying to tell you about the content of the book in a way that entices you.  Just an old school movie trailer haha （＾ν＾）